# CPU fan speed not increasing while in game

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan

I have a weird CPU fan issue - as long as I'm playing a game (Cities: Skylines), the CPU fan keeps spinning at the usual RPM while the CPU temperature starts increasing. As expected, the CPU overheats and the PC shuts down.

The weird part is that as soon as I quit the game, the fan kicks in and goes from ~3000 RPM to 5000+ RPM, trying to cooldown the CPU. I saw it in Open Hardware Monitor, but the change is also audible.

I'm looking for a way to either fix this behavior (BIOS update didn't help) or at least find a way to force the CPU fan to work at max speed.

I spend a couple of hours searching/trying anything I could think of, but besides physically removing fan control pins or finding out how to use RWEverything to circumvent the fan speed, I'm out of ideas.

OS: Windows 8.1

Motherboard: ASRock M3A785GMH/128M

Edit: BIOS settings didn't help - there is only target CPU temp/fan speed option and it doesn't change anything, even if disabled

Edit2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfgnQ.jpg Immediately after quitting - CPU temp goes down, fan RPM ramps up

Comment: Ever thought of getting a liquid cooling system?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx It's not a fix but an expensive workaround. If your fan doesn't work as expected you should fix your fan, not buy liquid cooling system.

Comment: Still an option. But you might want to check if you have enough thermal compound

Comment: @xR34P3Rx It's a 2009 motherboard, the rest of the hardware isn't much better... an entirely new PC will be cheaper than liquid cooling. I changed the thermal paste few months ago as I was also having overheat problems back then. I thought it's the same problem or I did it wrong, but then I noticed the fan being crazy.

Comment: @digibo when was the last time the fan was replaced? Or how old is it?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Please read the post carefully. "*as soon as I quit the game, the fan kicks in and goes from ~3000 RPM to 5000+ RPM, trying to cooldown the CPU*" -> doesn't sound like a fan issue

Comment: @digibo Does this also happen with other games, benchmarks or GPU-intensive programs? Or is this problem specific for this game?

Comment: @gronostaj Hm, a couple of minutes of Dota2 didn't lower the RPM, even increased it beyond 5000+ as expected, but now I started Cities and it's dropping towards below 3800. This is getting weird.

Comment: As this issue seems to center around a single game you may be better off contacting support at Paradox Interactive, or at least checking the forum there to see if anyone else has experienced similar issues...

Comment: If your system cooling policy  in the windows power properties is set to "passive" instead of active, it will do some really strange things, depending on the load and the continuation of that load.  Wouldnt hurt to check how that is set.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly I can edit out the name of the game, but I mentioned it as side info, maybe giving useful hint to someone, more knowledgeable, about the general situation, minimal requirements, Windows versions etc. I should rewrite my question - how can I stop random software affect my CPU fan speed?

Comment: @Psycogeek It's currently set to active. I tried changing the other settings too - Minimum processor settings is also at 100% (initially at 5% when testing).

Comment: @digibo - no, the name of the game is potentially useful, but getting in touch with the developers via the support channel may either shed light on why you're having the issue or alert them to an issue they were unaware of...

Answer (score 1):

Since you can ramp up fan speed by playing other games, we can rule out fan failure and motherboard's inability to control fan speed.

I can only guess that this specific game is doing something weird with CPU that unintentionally caps fan speed on this MoBo. I can think of few unfortunate combinations of game's behavior and driver/MoBo/BIOS bugs that could cause this issue.

Potential solutions that come to mind:

- Reset BIOS to defaults. If you don't do this, some BIOS bugs can survive upgrade.
- Update motherboard drivers, specifically chipset drivers. Update GPU drivers too. (In theory this issue has nothing to do with GPU. In practice it's unbelievable that such bug can exist, so you can't be sure GPU drivers are unrelated.)
- If nothing else works, [report a bug](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?forums/support-bug-reports.879/).

Comment: The usual procedures (BIOS upgrade/defaults) didn't help, I'll try more things (Windowed mode seemed to help, but then relaunching the game in Windowed mode killed the fan as usual). My guess is it's probably a Drivers/Windows/DirectX/Unity issue, rather than something that Paradox (you?) can do about. I'll make a bug report if I don't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable passive cooling in windows if you can
2. Unplug and plug in your fan
3. Disable any passive cooling options in BIOS
4. You can try a very low target temperature on BIOS
5. AMD used to allow CPUs to work in higher temperatures. You can try underclocking your CPU. (Just decrease the multiplier by 1 or 2)

[image]